# iPhone Game Having a statement checked every 50 points

Tags: iphone, objective-c, numbers

I've run into a little hurdle and wanted to see if somebody could help me!

I want to write an algorithm for an if statement that says:

```
if (for every 50 points)
{
//do something
}
```

I thought += 50 would do the trick, but nope.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? A for-loop inside an if?

Comment: I think you need to be more clear about this. Assuming these are points scored in a game: What if the player received 60 points at once? 150? 20?

Comment: What I mean is:

Do if statement at-

50 points, 100 points, 150 points, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((points % 50) == 0)
{
  // do something
}
```

Where points is an int variable containing your points. The if statement will be enterred for points 0, 50, 100, 150.. and so on

Comment: This won't work if you have for example points+= 13 in the "loop"

Answer (score 1):

```
if (points - lastCheckpoint >= 50) 
{ 
  // do something
  lastCheckpoint = points - (points % 50);
}
```

Start with an `int lastCheckpoint = 0;` during set-up, and this'll do the trick.
Caveat: If the points increase by 100 or more between checks, the `// do something` will only be triggered once.
If you want it to happen for every 50 points regardless, you can change the increment statement to be `lastCheckpoint += 50;` although this runs the risk of the `points` running far ahead of `lastCheckpoint`.

Edit: this will be more efficient:

```
if (points > nextCheckpoint)
{
  // do something
  nextCheckpoint = 50 + points - (points % 50);
}
```

Start with `int nextCheckpoint = 50;` This way, the test that's performed (presumably) every iteration of the game loop doesn't include a subtraction.

Comment: Yeah. What I definitely mean is:

Do something at:

50, 100, 150, etc.

Comment: I still get an issue where if the player has 0 points, they'll still advance, which I don't want to happen. How do I fix that?